# A strange case of singular fit in lme4 glmer - simple random structure with variation among groups

Tags: r, lme4

*Background*

I am trying to test for differences in wind speed data among different groups. For the purpose of my question, I am looking only on side wind (wind direction that is 90 deg from the individual), and I only care about the strength of the wind. Thus, I use absolute values. The range of wind speeds is 0.0004-6.8 m/sec and because I use absolute values, Gamma distribution describes it much better than normal distribution.

My data contains 734 samples from 68 individuals, with each individual having between 1-30 repeats. However, even if I reduce my samples to only include individuals with at least 10 repeats (which leaves me with 26 individuals and a total of 466 samples), I still get the problematic error.

*The model*

The full model is `Wind ~ a*b + c*d + (1|individual)`, but for the purpose of this question, the simple model of `Wind ~ 1 + (1|individual)` gives the same singularity error, so I do not think that the explanatory variables are the problem.
The complete code line is `glmer(Wind ~ 1 + (1|individual), data = X, family = Gamma(log))`

*The problem and the strange part*

When running the model, I get the `boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular` error, although, as you can see, I use a very simple model and random structure. **The strange part is that I can solve this by adding 0.1** to the Wind variable (i.e. `glmer(Wind+0.1 ~ 1 + (1|Tag), data = X, family = Gamma(log))` does not give any error). I honestly do not remember why I added 0.1 the first time I did it, but I was surprised to see that it solved the error.

*The question*

Is this a problem with `lme4`? Am I missing something? Any ideas what might cause this and why does me adding 0.1 to the variable solve this problem?

*Edit following questions*

1. I am not sure what's the best way to add data, so here is [a link to a csv file in Google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NAp2QHXM8qt7TWkUiz2HfET50o4LmSGE/view?usp=sharing)
2. using `glmmTMB` does not produce any warnings with the basic formula `glmmTMB(Wind ~ 1 + (1|Tag), data = X, family = Gamma(log))`, but gives convergence problems warnings ('non-positive-definite Hessian matrix') when using the full model (i.e., `Wind ~ a*b + c*d + (1|individual)`), which are then solved if I scale the continuous variables

Comment: Can't say without data, but check this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378939/dealing-with-singular-fit-in-mixed-models

Comment: What happens if you use a different package such as `glmmTMB` or `GLMMAdaptive` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I added data. I also looked (again) at the link you shared and did not find a solution to my problem. @RobertLong glmmTMB does not show the singular fit warning.